# Recursively generate dicts based on other dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to generate dicts recursively, I mean I had dict:

```
{98: [38, 39, 40, 41], 99: [38, 39, 40, 41], 100: [38, 39, 40, 41, 42]}
```

And I would like to get new dicts,

where

```
new_key = old_key*2, new_value = list(range(2*old_value[0], 2*(old_value[-1] + 1)))

new_key = old_key*2 + 1, new_value = list(range(2*old_value[0], 2*(old_value[-1] + 1)))
```

so, from the key = 98 I want to get key 196, 197 with the

```
values = list(range(2*old_value[0], 2*(old_value[-1] + 1)))
```

e.g. the next one

```
{196: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 197: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 198: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 199: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 200: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85], 201: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85]}
```

and so on
maybe any ideas how to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

## update:

I want to get not only the one next dict, but several dicts, so the rule is true for the every next dict that

new_key = old_key*2, new_value = list(range(2*old_value[0], 2*(old_value[-1] + 1)))

```
new_key = old_key*2 + 1, new_value = list(range(2*old_value[0], 2*(old_value[-1] + 1)))
```

where old_key, old_value is the items of previous dict (step back)

maybe the answer is close to

```
n = 1
while n < 3:
    rl = [{x*2**n: list(range(2**n*y[0], 2**n*(y[-1]+1))), x*2**n+1: list(range(2**n*y[0], 2**n*(y[-1]+1)))} for x, y in tiles_dict.items()]
    n += 1
    req_dict = {}
    for d in rl:
        req_dict.update(d)
    print(req_dict)
```

I am trying yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `list comprehension` to achieve this

```
d = {98: [38, 39, 40, 41], 99: [38, 39, 40, 41], 100: [38, 39, 40, 41, 42]}

# list-comprehension outputs a list of dictionaries
rl = [{x*2:list(range(2*y[0], 2*(y[-1]+1))), x*2+1:list(range(2*y[0], 2*(y[-1]+1)))} for x,y in d.items()]

# flattening the list of dictionaries
req_dict = {}
for d in rl:
    req_dict.update(d)
```

Output:

```
req_dict 
{196: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 197: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 198: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 199: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], 200: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85], 201: [76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85]}
```

Comment: that's great! Any idea, how automatically generate for the next dictionary, where the same rules:
 new_key = old_key*2, new_value = list(range(2*old_value[0], 2*(old_value[-1] + 1)))

new_key = old_key*2 + 1, new_value = list(range(2*old_value[0], 2*(old_value[-1] + 1)))

Comment: n = 1
    while n < 3:
        rl = [{x*(2^n): list(range((2^n)*y[0], (2^n)*(y[-1]+1))), x*(2^n)+1: list(range((2^n)*y[0], (2^n)*(y[-1]+1)))} for x, y in tiles_dict.items()]
        req_dict = {}
        for d in rl:
            req_dict.update(d)
        print(req_dict)  # does not work(

Comment: @Jane can you please update your question with the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Van Peer idea, I get

```
# looping over range 1 to 5
for n in range(1, 5):
    rl = [{x*(2**n): list(range((2**n)*y[0], (2**n)*(y[-1]+1))), x*(2**n)+1: list(range((2**n)*y[0], (2**n)*(y[-1]+1)))} for x, y in tiles_dict.items()]

req_dict = {}
for d in rl:
    req_dict.update(d)
print(req_dict)
```

Comment: Please do not post "thank you" posts as answers. Your answer does not differ from Peers solution, that it would justify an answer. Please delete this post.

Comment: @hellow, my post differs from Peers solution, my answer lets create dicts in loop

Comment: Not really, because you overwrite your rl every time you loop, so you just end with one rl in the very end.

Comment: I agree, because in my code all is tab-shifted in loop, when pasting formatting is removed. If you much insist I can delete this post.

Comment: That's what the preview pane is for ;)